# Copy artifacts generated by ng build in outdir to another folder

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, ng-build

I have an angular project. when we run ng build command the build artifacts are created in dist folder as we have set `"outDir": "dist",` in angular-cli.json. After this I have to manually copy these files from dist to Webcontent folder of java to generate a WAR file.

Is there any way to automate the process coping the artifacts. If I set the path of WebContent as outDir value `"outDir": "../server/WebContent",`  the build command is cleaning up the existing java files before generating build artifacts.

Any suggestions will help..

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following solution:

1. Add a [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) named `build` in your projects *package.json* file to execute your `ng build` command.
2. Also add a [post hook](https://www.marcusoft.net/2015/08/pre-and-post-hooks-for-npm-scripting.html) npm script named `postbuild` to copy your files.

The following describes how to achieve this on a **Nix* platform, and also provides a cross-platform solution.

---

#### *Nix (Linux, macOS, ... )

On *nix platforms npm utilizes `sh` as the default shell for running npm scripts. Therefore add the following to the `scripts` section of your projects *package.json*:

**package,json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng build",
  "postbuild": "cp -r dist/ ../server/WebContent"
}
```

This `postbuild` npm script utilizes the shells [cp](https://ss64.com/bash/cp.html) command to recursively copy artifacts from the `dist` directory to the `../server/WebContent` directory. The `postbuild` script will automatically run when the `build` script successfully completes.

**Running:**

Via your command line run the following command instead of `ng build`:

```
npm run build
```

---

#### Cross-platform (Linux, macOS, Windows, ... )

For a cross-platform solution firstly install [shx](https://github.com/shelljs/shx) - it’s a wrapper around [ShellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) Unix commands:

1. `cd` to your project directory.
2. Then run the following command:

   ```
   npm install -D shx
   ```

Define the `scripts` section of your projects *package.json* as follows:

**package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng build",
  "postbuild": "shx cp -r \"dist/*\" \"../server/WebContent\""
}
```

**Running:**

Via your command line run the following command instead of `ng build`:

```
npm run build
```